# Confirmation Dialog - call to backend design

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, dialog, frontend, confirmation

If the user clicks "confirm" in the dialog box, I have to make a service call to store the data entered by the user.(I'm using Angular Material.) Which of these options is better design wise?

A) pass the data from the parent component to the dialog component and call the service directly from the dialog

B) return boolean (value true if "confirm" selected by user in dialog) to parent component from dialog and the service call is made by the parent component

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I think it's a better idea to call the service from the component and not from the dialog. This way, you could think to have a "generic" dialog with a cancel and confirm button that should return data and that you could reuse in other components.